# can't connect to spotify kafka container, basic connection problems

Tags: java, docker, groovy, apache-kafka, spotify

stumbling at the basics with docker and kafka, cant get a client connection

what i've done so far

1) installed docker windows on windows 10.
2) open kitematic, and searched for kafka, and selected the spotify kafka  (wurstmeister image failed to start).
3) container fires up and i can see the image running in the container logs.
4) ip and ports reports docker port 9092 - and access port as localhost:32768

docker ps shows this 
7bf9f9278e64        spotify/kafka:latest   "supervisord -n"    2 hours ago         Up 57 minutes       0.0.0.0:32769->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->9092/tcp   kafka

docker-machine active, returns no active host

my groovy class (kind of cut and paste from an example setsup the connection like this

```
class KafkaProducer {

    String topicName = "wills topic"
    Producer<String, String> producer    
def init () {
    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.1.89:32768" )   //Assign localhost id and external port (9092 int)
    props.put("acks", "all")                            //Set acknowledgements for producer requests.
    props.put("retries", 0)                             //If the request fails, the producer can automatically retry,
    props.put("batch.size", 16384)                      //Specify buffer size in config
    props.put("linger.ms", 1)                           //Reduce the no of requests less than 0
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432)                //The buffer.memory controls the total amount of memory available to the producer for buffering.
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")

    producer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<String, String>(props)
}  ....
```

when i run this init i get errors say it cant resolve connection, for java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: 7bf9f9278e64:9092, which is the internal container port.  (my script is calling from my normal IDE desktop environment )

kitmatic says says this is the mapping.  so why cant i connect and then send ?
Also as i just download via kitematic where does one put the docker-compose.yml if you want to change the config.  Really not clear where one do do this.

```
18:05:41.022 [main] INFO  o.a.k.c.p.ProducerConfig:[.logAll:] > ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = all
    batch.size = 16384
    block.on.buffer.full = false
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.1.89:32768]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    interceptor.classes = null
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 1
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    timeout.ms = 30000
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

18:05:41.076 [main] INFO  o.a.k.c.p.ProducerConfig:[.logAll:] > ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = all
    batch.size = 16384
    block.on.buffer.full = false
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.1.89:32768]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = producer-1
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    interceptor.classes = null
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 1
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    timeout.ms = 30000
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

18:05:41.079 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name bufferpool-wait-time
18:05:41.083 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name buffer-exhausted-records
18:05:41.085 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.Metadata:[.update:] > Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(id = null, nodes = [192.168.1.89:32768 (id: -1 rack: null)], partitions = [])
18:05:41.401 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name connections-closed:
18:05:41.401 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name connections-created:
18:05:41.402 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name bytes-sent-received:
18:05:41.402 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name bytes-sent:
18:05:41.406 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name bytes-received:
18:05:41.406 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name select-time:
18:05:41.407 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name io-time:
18:05:41.409 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name batch-size
18:05:41.410 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name compression-rate
18:05:41.410 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name queue-time
18:05:41.410 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name request-time
18:05:41.410 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name produce-throttle-time
18:05:41.411 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name records-per-request
18:05:41.412 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name record-retries
18:05:41.412 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name errors
18:05:41.412 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name record-size-max
18:05:41.414 [main] WARN  o.a.k.c.p.ProducerConfig:[.logUnused:] > The configuration 'key.deserializer' was supplied but isn't a known config.
18:05:41.414 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.p.i.Sender:[.run:] > Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
18:05:41.414 [main] WARN  o.a.k.c.p.ProducerConfig:[.logUnused:] > The configuration 'value.deserializer' was supplied but isn't a known config.
18:05:41.416 [main] INFO  o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser:[.<init>:] > Kafka version : 0.10.1.1
18:05:41.416 [main] INFO  o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser:[.<init>:] > Kafka commitId : f10ef2720b03b247
18:05:41.417 [main] DEBUG o.a.k.c.p.KafkaProducer:[.<init>:] > Kafka producer started
18:05:41.430 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:[.maybeUpdate:] > Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request
18:05:41.430 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:[.initiateConnect:] > Initiating connection to node -1 at 192.168.1.89:32768.
18:05:41.434 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
18:05:41.434 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
18:05:41.435 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.m.Metrics:[.sensor:] > Added sensor with name node--1.latency
18:05:41.435 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.n.Selector:[.pollSelectionKeys:] > Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
18:05:41.436 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:[.handleConnections:] > Completed connection to node -1
18:05:41.452 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:[.maybeUpdate:] > Sending metadata request {topics=[wills topic]} to node -1
18:05:41.476 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:[.handleResponse:] > Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {wills topic=INVALID_TOPIC_EXCEPTION}
18:05:41.477 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.Metadata:[.update:] > Updated cluster metadata version 2 to Cluster(id = 8cjV2Ga6RB6bXfeDWWfTKA, nodes = [7bf9f9278e64:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], partitions = [])
18:05:41.570 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:[.maybeUpdate:] > Initialize connection to node 0 for sending metadata request
18:05:41.570 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:[.initiateConnect:] > Initiating connection to node 0 at 7bf9f9278e64:9092.
18:05:43.826 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:[.initiateConnect:] > Error connecting to node 0 at 7bf9f9278e64:9092:
java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: 7bf9f9278e64:9092
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:498)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$400(NetworkClient.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:645)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:552)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:258)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

appreciate help to get me over this first hurdle

Answer (score 3):

Try to set `--env ADVERTISED_HOST=192.168.1.89` and `--env ADVERTISED_PORT=32768` when starting the container. This is required because by default Kafka advertises the local host name (which is the container hostname, e.g. `7bf9f9278e64`) and this is not accessible from the host. As you are using port binding you need to advertise your host IP (e.g. `192.168.1.89`) and the mapped port (e.g. `32768`).

Comment: This is probably it. Also, you can pass `-p 9092:9092 -p 2181:2181` as command line args to `docker run` and you won't have the ports moving around on you.

Comment: skipped the kitematic as i can't control how its started.  I ran the run command from the powershell console as follows "docker run --detach --name kafka -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=192.168.1.89 --env ADVERVTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka" (after i removed the previous container).  it seems to start ok and "docker logs kafka" says its up.    I then run my client producer and looks healthier - but says repeatedly "WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient:[.handleResponse:] > Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {wills topic=INVALID_TOPIC_EXCEPTION}".

Comment: how dow you talk to the kafka process once running using docker commands.  there is this comment on kafka site "bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test"  but that requires i can communicate to the detached kafka and run a shell command.  how do you 'talk' to the detached container via docker ?

Comment: Those are all separate questions. You should go ahead and open new posts for this. I assume this question here is answered as the connection itself is now working.

Comment: ...and if it solved the problem also think about accepting the answer to help other people with the same issue to find the right solution ;-)